# how to start only idb services in data protector. Need to run autovacuum of database

Tags: data-protection

My all data protector services are down. I want to start auto vacuum of database. For that I need idb services up. Is there any way to start idb services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use omnisv -start -idb_only. it will check for only idb services